# Why is while (1 < a < 5) an infinite loop?

Tags: c, comparison-operators

```
int a = 2;   
while (1 < a < 5)  {
      printf("%d\n", a);
      a = a + 1;
}
```

In a C program, I have used the above code, but it is always counting infinitely. That means the test condition of the while loop is always true. But I could not understand why this is happening.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! It might be a surprise to you, but your question is off-topic here. We deal with computer *science* questions, not programming questions. Please see our [help on topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your question might be on-topic on [SO].

Comment: This code will help you. `printf("%d\n",1<-1);printf("%d\n",1<1);printf("%d\n",1<2);printf("%d\n",1<-1<5);printf("%d\n",1<1<5);printf("%d\n",1<2<5);printf("%d\n",1<5<5);printf("%d\n",1<6<5);` What happens is that the result of a comparison is either 0 or 1.

Comment: @burnabyRails Thanks , it's very helpful. Guess I'll need to learn more about this ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`1 < a < 5` is grouped as `(1 < a) < 5`.

For your value of `a`, `1 < a` returns `1` (true), so now your expression becomes `1 < 5`, which always evaluates to `1`, that's why you end up with an infinite loop.

The behavior you want can be obtained by writing `while((1 < a) && (a < 5))` instead.

Comment: "`1 < a` ... is cast to `int`" -- not really: `1 < a` has type `int` (and value `1`) to begin with.

Comment: Note that `1 < a` **is** either 0 or 1. It has an `int` type. No need to talk about `true` and casting here. In this respect, C differs from C++.

Comment: Could you point me towards a source on `operator<` returning an `int` in C? Edit: Turns out C doesn't have a boolean type. Pardon my C++.

Comment: @RcnSc: see [C11 6.5.8p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8p6).

Comment: @RcnSc [**6.5.8 Relational operators**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8p6): "Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. The result has type int."  [Footnote 107](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note107) is directly relevant:  "The expression a<b<c is not interpreted as in ordinary mathematics. As the syntax indicates, it means (a<b)<c; in other words, ''if a is less than b, compare 1 to c; otherwise, compare 0 to c''."

Comment: @RcnSc: also [C11 6.2.5p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p2): "An object declared as type `_Bool` is large enough to store the values 0 and 1." If you `#include <stdbool.h>` you can use `bool` instead of `_Bool`.

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edit. Have an upvote and this is a good first answer!

Comment: Thanks, have a nice day.

Comment: (1<a<5) is evaluated as ((1<a)<5) since "<" associates left to right .
1<a is either 0 or 1 , both are less then 5 , so the condition is always true(1).

Comment: Thanks , it's very helpful. Guess I'll need to learn more about this

Answer (score 1):

The expression `1 < a < 5` is `1` for any value of `a`, and `while (1)` loops.

It's grouped as `(1 < a) < 5` and `1 < a` is either `0` or `1`, which are both less than 5.

Did you want `1 < a && a < 5`?

Comment: That means :: (1<a<5) is evaluated as ((1<a)<5) since "<" associates left to right .
1<a is either 0 or 1 , both are less then 5 , so the condition is always true(1).